# python - fastest way to find unique "words" in a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, set, string-parsing

I have a string, s, with a length of 2*2*1092-1 = 4367 characters. Here are the first 15 characters:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

I am interested in the characters as couples; i.e. for the first 15 characters:

```
00, 01, 01, 00
```

My string only contains 0 and 1 and the possible couples are thus:

```
00, 01, 10 and 11
```

I want to get an unordered list of all the couples present in my string; i.e. for the first 15 characters:

```
00 and 01
```

What is the fastest way to do this in Python? Below are 3 methods (Python 3):

```
def method1(s):
    l_couples = [s[4*i:4*i+3] for i in range(1092)]
    set_couples = set(l_couples)

def method2(s):
    set_couples = []
    for i in range(1092):
        couple = s[4*i:4*i+3]
        if not couple in set_couples:
            set_couples += [couple]

def method3(s):
    set_couples = set()
    for i in range(1092):
        couple = s[4*i:4*i+3]
        set_couples |= set([couple])
```

I looped over each method 10k times and got these run times:

method1: 3.94s

method2: 5.64s

method3: 10.7s

Here is the entire string consisting of 4367 characters:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't 10 a possible couple?

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add it. Fixed. Not sure if it will ever appear for the actual data though, but that should have no influence on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only optimize on such a low level if you really need to!

There is no reason why you should micro-optimize for such a small input amount of data. A string of ~4000 characters is nearly nothing.

> Donald Knuth: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about
>   97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

So in this case the most readable and comprehensable solution would be the best.

But to be constructive, here is my proposal:

```
def method5(s):
    return {s[x:x+3] for x in xrange(0, len(s), 4)}

%timeit method5(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 us per loop
```

and here the method by another user:

```
def method4(s):
    return {s[4*i:4*i + 3] for i in range(len(s) / 4)}

%timeit method4(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 176 us per loop
```

and the benchmarks for the other methods:

```
%timeit method1(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 us per loop

%timeit method2(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 185 us per loop

%timeit method3(s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 513 us per loop
```

Comment: `xrange` should be `range` in Python 3. Also, include your benchmarks for the other methods.

Comment: The other method where posted in an answer by another user, but was deleted just a few moments ago. I will change my post and include the other methods again (but I can't give credit, because I can't remember his name).

Comment: I just tested the previous method, which was just removed. It returns 00 instead of 00 and 01. - I need the optimization, because I have millions of strings and sometimes with more than 4000 characters. - I haven't tagged the question with python3, so just leave the xrange in there.

Comment: @michaelkrisper: There's no need to include my method. Using `range`'s step argument is faster and looks nicer anyways.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Where are you getting this input from?

Comment: Thanks, it was pretty dumb of me not to use a proper step of 4 in the range function. I guess it can't be optimized any further. @Blender It is genotype data from www.1000genomes.org.

Comment: Ok, if you really need this performance, try executing the script with pypy or try converting it to C++ with shedskin or Cython. Here is a very good youtube tutorial for high performance python: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw9-GckD-gQ&list=WL1D64C7C5A89ABED0

Comment: I will eventually write it in C++. Thanks for the info on shedskin. I didn't know about that. I watched the great YouTube video already. Maybe he mentions shedskin and I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of brute force indexing through the string like it was an array, learn about Python's features like split, and iter, and zip:

```
def uniqueCouples(s):
    # get all the characters in a list, splitting on whitespace
    items = source.split()

    # create an iterator over this list
    it = iter(items)

    # using zip(it,it) will create a sequence of tuples, taking the generated list
    # in pairs; then use ''.join() to merge the tuples into couples; then find the 
    # set of unique pairs
    return set(''.join(couple) for couple in zip(it,it))
```

**EDIT**: adding performance numbers

To normalize out differences in hardware, I ran @michaelkrisper's `method5` on my system, and got 189 us (note also that method5 returns '0 1' and '0 0', not '01' and '00' as requested).

Testing the above solution as posted gives a time of about 370 us. Then I realized that I was calling `''.join` on every zipped tuple, instead of just on the reduced number of items after the set removed all the duplicates - who cares now if join is slow, we're only going to call it a couple of times.  Changing the return statement to:

```
    return [''.join(cpl) for cpl in set(zip(it,it))]
```

cuts the time to 209 us.

So maybe split() is slowing us down, so I'll change to using `islice`, creating a slicing iterator to walk through the input source string (of course this is now a bit more fragile, as any deviation in the input source format, like an extra space between values, will break our code, whereas using split, while a little slower, is more robust).  Changed to:

```
from itertools import islice
def uniqueCouples(s):
    it = islice(s, 0, None, 2)
    return [''.join(cpl) for cpl in set(zip(it,it))]
```

And the time now drops to 197 us.  Changing the list comprehension to use `map(''.join, set(zip(it,it)))` drops us down to about 194 us.

So I'm not sure where you get your information that split and join are slow - the big inefficiency I had in my submission was that I was calling join before using set to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I know split and join are quite slow. How fast is your method compared to the ones already provided?

Comment: Yes, I meant running split and join across all items in your iterator would be slow. I like your use of iter and your post-EDIT solution. Thanks.